# How is new humanism different from the catholic teaching?

Tags: catholicism

“A global educational pact is needed to educate us in universal solidarity and a **new humanism**,” Francis said in a [video message](https://www.lifesitenews.com/news/pope-francis-global-education-pact) to launch the initiative.

**Definition of [new humanism](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/new%20humanism). :**

> a 20th century doctrine marked by a belief in moderation, the dignity
>   of the human will, a sense of permanent values, and a dualistic order
>   of existence.

Does the definition of new humanism contradict or go against the Catholic teaching and if so how?

Comment: Francis may not have meant "the movement called new humanism" but "a new kind of humanism".

Comment: @DJClayworth, how is this new kind of humanism different from the humanism where objectives are attaching prime importance to human rather than divine or supernatural matters? That's a definition of normal humanism.

Comment: _A global educational pact is needed to educate us in universal solidarity and a new humanism_ Does this include China, by any chance ?

Comment: Humanism, per Merriam-Webster (your source for "new humanism", can also mean "devotion to human welfare: humanitarianism".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fr. Hardon, S.J.'s definition](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34016) of "[humanism](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/07538b.htm)" distinguishes "pagan humanism" and "Christian humanism":

> Name originally given to the intellectual, literary, and scientific movements of the fourteenth century through the early sixteenth. Their aim was to base every branch of learning on the culture of classical Greek and Roman antiquity. On its pagan side, it extolled the early non-Christian writers who stressed the full development of human nature, only vaguely interested in life after death. On its Christian side, believing humanists encouraged the free use of the treasures of antiquity without compromising the truths of the Gospel. Christian humanism began with Dante (1265-1321), while pagan humanism reached its peak in Petrarch (1304-74). Popes Pius II, Sixtus IV, and Leo X favored Christian humanism and did much to promote it. St. Thomas More (1478-1535) typified its best spirit in England. After the French Revolution the extreme humanistic spirit rebelled against Christian revelation and the Church.

"Pagan humanism," since it denies or neglects the supernatural order, is [naturalism](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=35058), which Pope Pius IX condemned in his [*Syllabus of Errors*](https://www.papalencyclicals.net/pius09/p9syll.htm) and Pope Leo XIII condemned in his encyclical [*Humanum Genus*](http://w2.vatican.va/content/leo-xiii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_l-xiii_enc_18840420_humanum-genus.html).